# How do I submit a form on selection of an item in autocomplete jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

here is JavaScript and HTML of my app

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#searchfield" ).autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/search.php",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
                        $("#search_form").submit(); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form id="search_form" action="search" method="get">
                <input id="searchfield" type="text" name="q" value="Search..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" />
                <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
                </p>
            </form>
```

I want that when someone is press the enter key on selected item from drop down menu. The form should be submit. and Page navigate to the target page.
The problem is that this code is not working. The form not submit when I hit enter key.
Please suggest me some code. Thanks

[image]

On this condition I want to submit the form.

Comment: Looks OK to me, please explain "not working". Any errors?

Comment: @David form should be submit when someone hits enter. but it's not working when I hits enter

Answer (score 2):

The plugin prevents event bubbling when the ENTER key is pressed and the menu is open:

```
case keyCode.ENTER:
case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
    // when menu is open and has focus
    if (self.menu.active) {
        // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
        // which causes forms to submit
        suppressKeyPress = true;
        event.preventDefault();
    }​
```

You can re-bind the keydown event and check for ENTER key press to submit the form:

```
$( "#searchfield" )
    .autocomplete()
    .bind('keydown', function() {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        if (key == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER || key == $.ui.keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER) {
            $('#search_form').submit();
        }
    });​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/wd4eN/)**

Comment: You might want to remove the `debugger;` statement.

Comment: Yep, just copy-pasted from my jsfiddle. Just needed 10sec to reformat my answer ;-)

Comment: @DidierGhys I have updated question. Please review this and answer me

Comment: I want that if the user hit enter on the selected item from the drop down menu suggestion then form should be submitted

Comment: @DidierGhys But it's just filled the input field and not submit the form

Comment: In my demo or in your implementation of this solution ? I added a "return true" in my demo so the form actually submits, but that was just for the sake of the example...